# What are the possible values for integer right angle sides with given hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry, triangles

By giving you a Right triangle with Hypotenuse of 35 units, what are the possible integer values for the sides of the right triangle?

It's easy to know the integer values when we know one of the right triangle sides by factoring $a^2+b^2=c^2 \Leftrightarrow a^2=(b+c)(b-c)$ but when $c$ is given we can't factor $a^2+b^2$ in real numbers.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Trial and error is fast.  Otherwise, you can start with the  solutions to $a^2+b^2=5^2, c^2+d^2=7^2$ and use the product formula for sums of two squares (trivial in this case).

Comment: $35^2\neq 33^2+14^2$.

Comment: $35^2=21^2+28^2$. See please my hint.

Answer (score 1):

We know that if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides-lengths of the right-angled triangle, where $c$ is a length of the hypotenuse and $a$ is even, then there are naturals, $m$, $n$ and $d$, where $m>n$, $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m$ and $n$ have the opposite parity, for which $a=2mnd$, $b=(m^2-n^2)d$ and $c=(m^2+n^2)d$.

Thus, $(m^2+n^2)d=35$ and the rest is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$a^2+b^2=35^2$$ by $AM-GM$ we get $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq ab$$ so we get
$$ab\le \frac{35^2}{2}$$ if $$b\le a$$ we get
$$b^2\le ab\le \frac{35^2}{2}$$

Comment: Why do you need the AM-GM inequality to conclude that?  Clearly, $B≤A,A+B=C\implies B≤AB≤\frac C2$.

Comment: Very nice idea, but this tends to hold very large variaties when c tends to be a large number such as 100 or 200.

Comment: i like the $AM-GM$ inequality lulu

Answer (score 0):

We have a theorem that if prime $p=4k+3$ and $p|a^2+b^2$ then $p|a$ and $p|b$ so in our case $p=7$. So we have $a=7x$ and $b=7y$, so we have $x^2+y^2 = 25$ and for this we have well know solutions 3 and 4.

Comment: do  you mean 5 instead of 7?

Comment: @PouJa No I meant 7